# What is the right way to query :has_many when condition is in :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :companies, :through => :profiles
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :users, :through => :profiles
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end
```

when I want to query all companies form user. I just type

```
u = User.find(:first)
companies = u.companies
```

But when I want to query only companies that have

```
profile.is_publish == ture
```

---

### What is the right way I should do

**First:** I should create method in User to do that

```
def published_companies
  companies.where('profiles.is_publish' => true)
end

companies = u.published_companies
```

**Second:** I should create scope in Company

```
scope :published, joins(:profiles).where('profiles.is_publish' => true)

companies = u.companies.published
```

**Third:** I should create a scope in Profile

```
companies = u.profile.published.companies
```

the first way is easy one and the third is cool but I don't know How to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the scope on `Company` like:

```
scope :published, where(:is_publish => true)
```

Then on user you call:

```
user.companies.published
```

To check the validness of the code you can use `to_sql` method.

Comment: But :is_publish is in Profile

Comment: Move this scope to `Profile` and call like: `u.profiles.published.map(&:company)`. But this somehow looks not so pretty, so try to experiment with your 2nd solution with scope on `Company`. `u.companies.published` looks much better, just be sure that SQL is valid.